# Debug C++ dll imported by a C# visual studio 2010 addin

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I am working in a VS.net 2010 addin that is designed in this way.

- Addin wrapper -> C#
- Addin logic -> Pure C++ dll

when I try to debug the adding I can get until the C# code calls the c++ dll function.

I have checked the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" checkbox from the C# properties project.

I have copied the c++ pdb's to their respective dll's folders.

Answer (score 0):

After few weeks I have finally found the solution, I am posting it in case any other developer needs something similar.

Solution:
You cannot attach your projects (at least the way is asked above) to a devenv.exe process, otherwise it will just attach to the C# dll.
So, the simple step is set devenv.exe as your dll solution start project.

Thats it!